# Build librdkafa Static Library for iOS

Tags: apache-kafka

I was able to compile a static version of librdkafa for MacOS easy enough:

```
./configure --prefix=$TEMP_DIR \
  --disable-sasl \
  --enable-static
make
make install
```

I'm assuming the above configuration worked since I'm compiling on the platform that I am targeting.

For iOS I'm specifying the architecture type like so:

```
./configure --prefix=$TEMP_DIR \
  --arch=arm64 \
  --disable-sasl \
  --enable-static
make
make install
```

But I get a compilation error:

```
gcc  -shared -dynamiclib -Wl,-install_name,/Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/temp/lib/librdkafka.1.dylib rdkafka.o rdkafka_broker.o rdkafka_msg.o rdkafka_topic.o rdkafka_conf.o rdkafka_timer.o rdkafka_offset.o rdkafka_transport.o rdkafka_buf.o rdkafka_queue.o rdkafka_op.o rdkafka_request.o rdkafka_cgrp.o rdkafka_pattern.o rdkafka_partition.o rdkafka_subscription.o rdkafka_assignor.o rdkafka_range_assignor.o rdkafka_roundrobin_assignor.o rdkafka_feature.o rdcrc32.o crc32c.o rdaddr.o rdrand.o rdlist.o tinycthread.o rdlog.o rdstring.o rdkafka_event.o rdkafka_metadata.o rdregex.o rdports.o rdkafka_metadata_cache.o rdavl.o rdkafka_sasl.o rdkafka_sasl_plain.o rdkafka_interceptor.o rdkafka_msgset_writer.o rdkafka_msgset_reader.o rdvarint.o rdbuf.o rdunittest.o rdkafka_sasl_scram.o snappy.o rdgz.o rdkafka_lz4.o xxhash.o rddl.o rdkafka_plugin.o -o librdkafka.1.dylib -L/usr/local/Cellar/lz4/1.8.1.2/lib -llz4 -lpthread -lz -L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_1/lib -lssl -ldl
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_BIO_ctrl", referenced from:
      _rd_base64_encode in rdkafka_sasl_scram.o
  "_BIO_f_base64", referenced from:
      _rd_kafka_sasl_scram_fsm in rdkafka_sasl_scram.o
      _rd_base64_encode in rdkafka_sasl_scram.o
```

The actual error is much longer so I'm posting only the part I think is relevant.

Here is the configuration summary that is printed right at the start of compilation:

```
prefix                   /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/temp
  ARCH                     arm64
  CPU                      generic
  GEN_PKG_CONFIG           y
  ENABLE_DEVEL             n
  ENABLE_VALGRIND          n
  ENABLE_REFCNT_DEBUG      n
  ENABLE_SHAREDPTR_DEBUG   n
  ENABLE_LZ4_EXT           y
  ENABLE_SSL               y
  ENABLE_SASL              n
  MKL_APP_NAME             librdkafka
  MKL_APP_DESC_ONELINE     The Apache Kafka C/C++ library
  MKL_DISTRO               osx
  SOLIB_EXT                .dylib
  CC                       gcc
  CXX                      g++
  LD                       ld
  NM                       nm
  OBJDUMP                  objdump
  STRIP                    strip
  CPPFLAGS                 -gstrict-dwarf -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align
  PKG_CONFIG               pkg-config
  INSTALL                  install
  HAS_LDFLAGS_STATIC       n
  LIB_LDFLAGS              -shared -dynamiclib -Wl,-install_name,$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(LIBFILENAME)
  RDKAFKA_VERSION_STR      0.11.3
  MKL_APP_VERSION          0.11.3
  LIBS                     -L/usr/local/Cellar/lz4/1.8.1.2/lib -llz4 -lpthread -lz -L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_1/lib -lssl -ldl
  CFLAGS                   -I/usr/local/Cellar/lz4/1.8.1.2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_1/include
  CXXFLAGS                 -Wno-non-virtual-dtor
  SYMDUMPER                $(NM) -g
  exec_prefix              /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/temp
  bindir                   /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/temp/bin
  sbindir                  /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/temp/sbin
  libexecdir               /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/temp/libexec
  datadir                  /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/temp/share
  sysconfdir               /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/temp/etc
  sharedstatedir           /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/temp/com
  localstatedir            /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/temp/var
  libdir                   /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/temp/lib
  includedir               /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/temp/include
  infodir                  /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/temp/info
  mandir                   /Users/przemeklach/dev/artifact_staging/temp/man
```

This error raises two questions for me: 1) Am I specifying the architecture correctly in my configure and 2) Why would it complain about undefined symbols for an architecture I'm not trying to build for?

Comment: On an unrelated note - mobile devices are highly susceptible to timeout exceptions via poor or unreliable networks, therefore using Kafka clients on a mobile device are generally avoided. You could try the Kafka REST proxy, then you'll been sending HTTP requests to it from mobile, which generate Kafka messages

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up. Having worked in mobile for a bit I had this feeling in the back of my mind that this may be an issue but I hadn't come across anything yet, til now, to confirm my suspicions. I will investigate the proxy approach.